# XPath expression to access feed rate value

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to access the feed rate of 0.8785 (see code below) using XPath:

```
<Streams>
  <DeviceStream name="Mori" uuid="001">
    <ComponentStream component="Path" name="path" componentId="pth">
      <Samples>
        <PathFeedrate dataItemId="fd1"
                      timestamp="2015-04-02T13:32:17.1810014Z"
                      name="feedrate"
                      sequence="6499">0.875</PathFeedrate>
        <PathFeedrate dataItemId="fd2"
                      timestamp="2015-04-02T12:09:33.7752758Z"
                      name="Fovr"
                      sequence="36"
                      subType="OVERRIDE">100</PathFeedrate>
        <FeedrateOverride dataItemId="fd3"
                          timestamp="2015-04-02T12:09:33.7752758Z"
                          name="Rovr"
                          sequence="37"
                          subType="RAPID">100</FeedrateOverride>
      </Samples>
```

Comment: And I am trying to get free beer for the rest of my life. I pray for it every day.  Show us what you tried so far, aka "Da code,plz!". And by the way: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath expression

```
//PathFeedrate[@dataItemId='fd1']
```

will evaluate to `0.875` given the XML you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried your suggested comment and it works.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways

```
/Streams/DeviceStream/ComponentStream/Samples/PathFeedrate[1]
```

or

```
//PathFeedrate[1]
```

or

```
/Streams/DeviceStream/ComponentStream/Samples/PathFeedrate[. = '0.875']
```

or

```
//PathFeedrate[. = '0.875']
```

or

```
/Streams/DeviceStream/ComponentStream/Samples/PathFeedrate[@timestamp= '2015-04-02T13:32:17.1810014Z']
```

or

```
//PathFeedrate[@timestamp= '2015-04-02T13:32:17.1810014Z']
```

There are many ways to find what you are looking, but a lot depends on the context of you xpath and or xslt

Comment: Many thanks for your comprehensive comments . I have tried all the of them and they works. Thanks again

Comment: @Tim does it answer your question?